# How do I sort an array of nested types?

Tags: algorithm, fortran, qsort

I have the following data structure in Fortran 95:

```
        type :: timestamp_record
                integer                                 :: year
                integer                                 :: month
                integer                                 :: day
                integer                                 :: hour
                integer                                 :: minute
                integer                                 :: second
        end type
​
        type :: foo_record
                type(timestamp_record)                  :: timestamp
                integer                                 :: foo
                integer                                 :: bar
                integer                                 :: baz
        end type
​
        type(foo_record),dimension(10000)               :: my_array
​
```

I want to sort `my_array` by:

```
   timestamp%year
   timestamp%month
   timestamp%day
   timestamp%hour
   timestamp%minute
   timestamp%second
```

I have seen that there are qsort and qsort64 available, but I do not understand what shall I use as length.

Also I see that there is a need to provide the comparison function (similar to C `qsort`).

Three questions:

1. Where can I find an example of `qsort` implemented for two or three fields?
2. Can I use it even for this case where I want to sort an array of nested `type`s?
3. Are `type` structures called struct in Fortran?

Comment: There is no `qsort` procedure in Fortran (95 or otherwise), so you will need to consult the documentation for whichever procedure you have found.

Comment: "Type structures" are called Derived Types in Fortran

Comment: So these are basically functions provided by the compilers that are not part of the standard:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/805-4942/6j4m3r8vn/index.html

https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/fortran-compiler-oneapi-dev-guide-and-reference/top/language-reference/a-to-z-reference/q-to-r/qsort.html

Comment: @M.E. Yes. You will either have to write your own, or an alternative is to call the qsort routine from the C library.

Comment: @M.E. BTW why the archaic Fortran95? I hope you don't just mean "free format fortran" (as opposed to fixed format). Almost everybody should be using Fortran 2003 or later nowadays

Comment: You can just call the C's qsort. That is best done through Fortran 2003 interoperability. Also, there are many Fortran sorting procedures available too.

Comment: Given the comments I will have a detailed look on the new features introduced by Fortran 2003 and consider moving to it. My expectation is that the core is the same for the kind of things I am trying to do in Fortran.

Comment: @M.E. Fortran is incredibly backward compatible. You can consider Fortran 2003 as a superset of Fortran 95

Comment: I often make the time a double precision number of seconds from an epoch, and sort it by that single number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cannot comment on where you find an example code. That is off-topic here, but examples do exist. Use we search. Try sites like Github or RosettaCode.

However, it is good to note how structures are typically sorted. You most often create a comparison function that compares two object and says how should they be order, which of them should go first.

For example, from my code

```
  function CompareWMPoints(Aptr,Bptr) bind(C,name="CompareWMPoints") result(res)
    use iso_c_binding
    integer(c_int)         :: res
    type(c_ptr),value :: Aptr,Bptr
    type(WMPoint),pointer  :: A,B

    call c_f_pointer(Aptr,A)
    call c_f_pointer(Bptr,B)

    if ((A%xi+(A%yj-1)*Prnx+(A%zk-1)*Prnx*Prny) < (B%xi+(B%yj-1)*Prnx+(B%zk-1)*Prnx*Prny)) then
      res = -1_c_int
    else if ((A%xi+(A%yj-1)*Prnx+(A%zk-1)*Prnx*Prny) > (B%xi+(B%yj-1)*Prnx+(B%zk-1)*Prnx*Prny)) then
      res =  1_c_int
    else if (A%distx**2+A%disty**2+A%distz**2 < B%distx**2+B%disty**2+B%distz**2) then
      res = -1_c_int
    else if (A%distx**2+A%disty**2+A%distz**2 > B%distx**2+B%disty**2+B%distz**2) then
      res =  1_c_int
    else
      res =  0_c_int
    end if

  end function CompareWMPoints
```

This compares two objects, `A` and `B`. You can reference any other structure that is nested inside these two objects. The result of the comparison is an integer (-1, 1 or 0).

Note: `A` and `B` are passed through C pointers because the C `qsort()` is used. That is avoided by using a Fortran sorting subroutine. One could use `type(...), intent(in) ::` but that is not legal if the type is not interoperable.

Because I am lazy I just call the `qsort()` from the C standard library

```
  interface
    subroutine qsort(array,elem_count,elem_size,compare) bind(C,name="qsort")
      import
      type(c_ptr),value       :: array
      integer(c_size_t),value :: elem_count
      integer(c_size_t),value :: elem_size
      type(c_funptr),value    :: compare !int(*compare)(const void *, const void *)
    end subroutine qsort !standard C library qsort
  end interface
```

but you can call any other subroutine that uses comparison functions.

There is a certain performance penalty that comes from using these callback functions but it is often not that important.

Comment: Apparently, implementing your own qsort function is not that complex (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort). In fact it looks so simple that one might question if it is worth the glue logic to call C for that or learn those functions provided as extension by compilers/libraries.

Comment: Is the sample code provided here Fortran 95 or Fortran 2003? (I read above that Fortran-C interoperability is improved in the 2003 revision)

Comment: It is Fortran 2003. If you are going to call a Fortran sorting subroutine with callbacks, you might be able to stay within the old Fortran 95 although there is now little reason to do so on purpose.

Comment: For the particular case of date & time specified with six numbers, it can be convenient to convert to a single time number.   Julian Day Number will accomplish this.  Then you can sort on that single numeric value.  There are algorithms on the web for the conversion.