# How to create an array and sort lines in Fortran

Tags: sorting, fortran, line

I would like to sort output lines in an ascending order based on the numeric values present in a particular column.

After reading the following input file:

```
  h5     1     1.0080      0.086     A    2.42146271591e-01    6.276000e-02
  ho     1     1.0080      0.443     A    0.00000000000e+00    0.000000e+00
   c     6    12.0100      0.632     A    3.39966950842e-01    3.598240e-01
   o     8    16.0000     -0.546     A    2.95992190115e-01    8.786400e-01
  oh     8    16.0000     -0.615     A    3.06647338784e-01    8.803136e-01
```

through the following Fortran code:

```
    INTEGER NIA,NIB
    REAL NRA,NRB,NRC,NRD
    REAL FACTOR_1,FACTOR_2
    CHARACTER*2 ATOM
    CHARACTER*1 TYPE

    OPEN(3,FILE='input')

    NIA = 0 
    NIB = 0
    
    NRA = 0.0
    NRB = 0.0
    NRC = 0.0
    NRD = 0.0
    
    FACTOR_1 = 10.0
    FACTOR_2 = 0.239006

OPEN(4,FILE='lammps.data', STATUS='NEW')

DO I=1,5

    READ (3,*) ATOM,NIA,NRA,NRB,TYPE,NRC,NRD
    
    IF (ATOM.EQ.'c') THEN
    NRC = NRC * FACTOR_1        
    NRD = NRD * FACTOR_2
    NIB = 1
    
    
    ELSE IF (ATOM.EQ.'h5') THEN
    NRC = NRC * FACTOR_1 
    NRD = NRD * FACTOR_2
    NIB = 2

    ELSE IF (ATOM.EQ.'o') THEN
    NRC = NRC * FACTOR_1        
    NRD = NRD * FACTOR_2
    NIB = 3
    
    ELSE IF (ATOM.EQ.'oh') THEN             
    NRC = NRC * FACTOR_1
    NRD = NRD * FACTOR_2
    NIB = 4

    ELSE IF (ATOM.EQ.'ho') THEN
    NRC = NRC * FACTOR_1
    NRD = NRD * FACTOR_2
    NIB = 5

    END IF
    
    WRITE(4,100) 'pair_coeff',NIB,NIB,NRB,NRD,NRC
100 FORMAT (A10,1X,I3,1X,I3,1X,F10.6,1X,F10.6,1X,F10.6)
    
    END DO

CLOSE(4)
CLOSE(3)

END
```

I get the following output:

```
  pair_coeff   2   2   0.086000   0.015000   2.421463
  pair_coeff   5   5   0.443000   0.000000   0.000000
  pair_coeff   1   1   0.632000   0.086000   3.399670
  pair_coeff   3   3  -0.546000   0.210000   2.959922
  pair_coeff   4   4  -0.615000   0.210400   3.066473
```

I would like to know how I could sort the lines above in ascending order based on the integer numbers of the second column and get the following output instead:

```
  pair_coeff   1   1   0.632000   0.086000   3.399670
  pair_coeff   2   2   0.086000   0.015000   2.421463
  pair_coeff   3   3  -0.546000   0.210000   2.959922
  pair_coeff   4   4  -0.615000   0.210400   3.066473
  pair_coeff   5   5   0.443000   0.000000   0.000000
```

Comment: If you are going to sort whole "lines" of entities then you would probably find it easier putting the elements of each line (whatever they are) into a user-defined type first. Most sorting algorithms - which require swaps - will work much more efficiently on whole entities. Another advantage is that you can go on to sort on whichever field you desire.

Comment: BTW, that's a VERY repetitive (and slightly unnecessary) if-else block, since the same numerical factors are applied to each type of atom.

Comment: @lastchance I tend to disagree, it's usually more efficient to call the sorting algorithm with a particular field, get an index array, and use the index array to the sort the structure afterwards. That said, sort performances are not critical for such small number of elements.

Comment: You have to find/write a sorting algorithm that derives an index array from a particular field, then use this index array to sort the other fields. You can find such routine at https://websites.pmc.ucsc.edu/~fnimmo/eart290c_17/NumericalRecipesinF77.pdf , page 330. It is in Fortran 77, but it still works.

Comment: The portable library contains a [`QSORT()`](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/fortran-compiler/developer-guide-reference/2023-0/qsort.html) built-in function so you don't have to roll your own. You do need to roll you own comparison function and use it as a callback to qsort.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou The portability library does not actually contain any algorithms in the functions. It only provides interfaces to well known C standard library functions, in this case to qsort. One can easily write one's own Fortran interface https://stackoverflow.com/a/67633652/721644  The linked answer is applicable to derived types so is similar to the second half of the answer by lastchance.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend storing the fields of each line in some user-defined type. Apart from "atom", "nia" and "nra" I don't know what these quantities represent in your code; I think it would be a good idea to use more descriptive names.

```
type entity
   character(len=2) atom
   integer nia, nib
   real(real64) nra, nrb, nrc, nrd
   character ty
end type entity
```

You can then store an array of such entities:

```
type(entity) A(N)
```

For purposes of re-use it is convenient to define user types in a module.

You can use any sorting routine that you like. The code below uses selection sort, but there are much faster algorithms for large datasets. Note that (i) I have followed PierU's suggestion and actually sorted indices first (which involves much less copying during swaps); and (ii) written a comparator function so that I can sort on whichever field I want:

```
logical function compare( p, q )
   type(entity), intent(in) :: p, q
   compare = p%nib < q%nib                   ! here you decide which field to compare
end function compare
```

Finally, Fortran is great for allowing you to do whole-array operations on only a single component of an array of user-defined type:

```
A%nrc = A%nrc * FACTOR1
```

Putting this all together:

```
!=======================================================================

module chemistry
   use iso_fortran_env
   implicit none

   type entity
      character(len=2) atom
      integer nia, nib
      real(real64) nra, nrb, nrc, nrd
      character ty
   end type entity

end module chemistry

!=======================================================================

module sort
   use chemistry
   implicit none

contains

   !-------------------------------------

   subroutine swap( a, b )
      integer, intent(inout) :: a, b
      integer temp

      temp = a
      a = b
      b = temp

   end subroutine swap

   !-------------------------------------

   subroutine selectionSort( A, less )
      type(entity), intent(inout) :: A(:)
      logical, external :: less

      integer, allocatable :: dummy(:)

      integer n
      integer i, j, jmin
   
      n = size( A )
      dummy = [ ( i, i = 1, n ) ]      ! stores indices

      do i = 1, n - 1
         jmin = i
         do j = i + 1, n
            if ( less( A(dummy(j)), A(dummy(jmin)) ) ) jmin = j
         end do
         if ( jmin /= i ) call swap( dummy(i), dummy(jmin) )
      end do
           
      A = A( dummy )

   end subroutine selectionSort

   !-------------------------------------

end module sort

!=======================================================================

program test
   use iso_fortran_env
   use chemistry
   use sort
   implicit none

   integer, parameter :: N = 5
   real(real64), parameter :: FACTOR1 = 10.0
   real(real64), parameter :: FACTOR2 = 0.239006
   character(len=*), parameter :: FMT_OUT = "( a10, 2( 1x, i3 ), 3( 1x, f10.6 ) )"
   character(len=2), parameter :: names(*) = [ "c ", "h5", "o ", "oh", "ho" ]

   type(entity) A(N)
   integer i

   ! Read input and assign index of item
   open( 3, file="input" )
   do i = 1, N
      read( 3, * ) A(i)%atom, A(i)%nia, A(i)%nra, A(i)%nrb, A(i)%ty, A(i)%nrc, A(i)%nrd
      A(i)%nib = findloc( names, A(i)%atom, 1 )
      if ( A(i)%nib <= 0 ) then
         write( *, * ) "Item not in database"
         stop
      end if
   end do
   close( 3 )

   ! Apply factors
   A%nrc = A%nrc * FACTOR1
   A%nrd = A%nrd * FACTOR2

   ! Sort
   call selectionSort( A, compare )

   ! Output
   do i = 1, N
      write( *, FMT_OUT ) "pair_coeff", A(i)%nib, A(i)%nib, A(i)%nrb, A(i)%nrd, A(i)%nrc
   end do

contains

   logical function compare( p, q )
      type(entity), intent(in) :: p, q
      compare = p%nib < q%nib                   ! here you decide which field to compare
   end function compare

end program test
```

Output:

```
pair_coeff   1   1   0.632000   0.086000   3.399670
pair_coeff   2   2   0.086000   0.015000   2.421463
pair_coeff   3   3  -0.546000   0.210000   2.959922
pair_coeff   4   4  -0.615000   0.210400   3.066473
pair_coeff   5   5   0.443000   0.000000   0.000000
```